# argparse optional dependency for optional argument

Tags: python, argparse

I need to get to work something like this:

```
./foo.py [-b option [-a]]
```

with argparse. I thought about using sub_parsers, but I don't know how to make it work.

Comment: As far as doing it with argparse logic, there seems to be an open-ended ticket for this exact functionality: http://bugs.python.org/issue11588

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The straightforward way is to simply add rules in the codes that gets your options to throw an error if -a is there and not b (and document it in the user help). You can also override the usage string using the `usage` keyword: http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#usage

sub_parsers are nice, but I don't think they fit your needs. Their usecase is more like putting a lot of features in a single executable (think svn add, svn ci, svn co, etc)

Comment: I agree. While I am sure you could make use of the more advanced features of argparse, this is super simple like you said as checking the values.